# How can a line skip a column in an aligned environment?

Tags: align, amsmath

I'm trying to align an equation block with eight terms in the following layout:

```
A....... B..............
C.....   D....    E......
F......  G......  H...
```

I've tried just leaving out the third column in the first line, but that pushes the third column far right:

```latex
\begin{gather}
\begin{aligned}
&\text{A.......} &&\text{B..............} \\
&\text{C.....}   &&\text{D....}    &&\text{E......} \\
&\text{F......}  &&\text{G......}  &&\text{H...}
\end{aligned}
\end{gather}
```

[image: latex aligned skip column]

If this were a table, I would merge the second and third cells of the first row using `\multicolumn`.

How can I position E and H before the end of B?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on the width of `B...`, you can set it inside a `\mathrlap`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
  \begin{aligned}
    &\text{A.......} && \mathrlap{\text{B..............}} \\
    &\text{C.....}   && \text{D....}    && \text{E......} \\
    &\text{F......}  && \text{G......}  && \text{H...}
  \end{aligned}
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Cool, thanks! This works because B is always longer than either D or G in my case.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use `aray`? With it is siple (as you noted in question):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
    \begin{equation}
    \setcellgapes{3pt}
    \makegapedcells\bigotimes
\begin{array}{lll}
\gamma^2 = \alpha^2 + \beta^2  
                &\multicolumn{2}{l}{\displaystyle
                \sin{x}= \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^i}{(2i+1)!}x^{2i+1}
                                    }                       \\
\text{C.....}   &\text{D....}    &\text{E......}            \\
\text{F......}  &\text{G......}  &\text{H...}
\end{array}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is this recommended for equations? Would the spacing be correct? I should have said that the words in my question are just placeholders for terms of mathematical equations.

Comment: @danijar, as you see, in the all rows are math term (`\alpha`, `\beta`, \text{C ...}` etc), so, you can put there any equation instead them. To convince you, I wrote two equation in the first row i of the arrax. Note, math term inside them are in-line math expresions. See edited example!.

Comment: Good to know, thanks. Would you recommend this over the solution using `\mathrlap`? It seems like tables come in handy for more complex situations but for now `\mathrlap` is a simpler solution.

Comment: Why you would use `\mathrlap`? In showed example I don't see anything for fine tuning of math expression (for example `sum`) with it.

Comment: @danijar, now I see, where you like to use `mathrlap` (instead of the /standard/ `multicolumn`) This use is (according to my opinion) against to standard syntax for table settings. I do not recommend it. I suggest you to ask new question: *What is correct: use `mathrlap` or `multicolumn` for multi column long equations`*.  With some luck you will get competent answers from LaTeX gurus :-)