# Underbrace that spans the width of the align column

Tags: align, amsmath, underbrace

I have [aligned display equations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/528492/61219) similar to the following example. I'm using words as placeholders here, but they are actually mathematical expressions:

```
\begin{gather}
\begin{alignedat}{3}
 (& \text{dolor}       && +\text{adipiscing} && +\text{amet} \\
  & \text{consectetur} && -\text{sit}        && -\text{elit} && )
\end{alignedat}
\end{gather}
```

[image: aligned display equation]

I want to add an underbrace to each alignment column. In other words, there are three groups of terms, each consisting of one term in the first and one in the second row:

```
\begin{gather}
\begin{alignedat}{3}
 (& \text{dolor} && +\text{adipiscing} && +\text{amet} \\
  &  \underbrace{\text{consectetur}}_{\text{first}}
  && \underbrace{-\text{sit}}_{\text{second}}
  && \underbrace{-\text{elit}}_{\text{third}} && )
\end{alignedat}
\end{gather}
```

[image: aligned display equation with naive underbraces]

Each underbrace only spans the width of its term in the second row. Instead, I would like to place an underbrace that spans the widest term in its align column, indicating that it applies to all terms in this column. Here is a photoshop example:

[image: aligned display equation with underbrace labels]

Is this possible in a generic way, i.e. without having to manually create phantom elements of the longest term of each column for every such equation block?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `eqparbox` package for that. I would not extend the underbrace over the signs, but keep them outside.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather}
\begin{alignedat}{3}
 (& \eqmakebox[A][l]{dolor} && +\eqmakebox[B][l]{adipiscing} &&
 +\eqmakebox[C][l]{amet} \\
  &  \underbrace{\eqmakebox[A][l]{consectetur}}_{\text{first}}
  && -\underbrace{\eqmakebox[B][l]{sit}}_{\text{second}}
  && -\underbrace{\eqmakebox[C][l]{elit}}_{\text{third}} && )
\end{alignedat}
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or following suggestions by barbara beeton.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather}
\begin{alignedat}{3}
 (&\, \eqmakebox[A][l]{dolor} && \eqmakebox[B][l]{$\,{}+\text{adipiscing}$} &&
 \eqmakebox[C][l]{$\,{}+\text{amet}$} \\
  &  \underbrace{\eqmakebox[A][l]{consectetur}}_{\text{first}}
  && \underbrace{\eqmakebox[B][l]{${}-\text{sit}$}}_{\text{second}}
  && \underbrace{\eqmakebox[C][l]{${}-\text{elit}$}}_{\text{third}} && )
\end{alignedat}
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather}
\begin{alignedat}{3}
 (\!&\, \eqmakebox[A][l]{dolor} && \,\eqmakebox[B][l]{${}+\text{adipiscing}$} &&
 \,\eqmakebox[C][l]{${}+\text{amet}$} \\
  &  \underbrace{\eqmakebox[A][l]{consectetur}}_{\text{first}}
  && \underbrace{\eqmakebox[B][l]{${}-\text{sit}$}}_{\text{second}}
  && \underbrace{\eqmakebox[C][l]{${}-\text{elit}$}}_{\text{third}} && )
\end{alignedat}
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure why, but the alignment is a little bit off.  A manual adjustment adding a thinspace at the beginning of each segment in the first line would probably line things up, but obviously it's not the best approach.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks for the heads up! I agree. I actually would not include the signs in the underbraces.

Comment: But neither element in the first column has a sign.  What about adding a zero-height hphantom of the braces to the first line?  (Might have to adjust the vertical spacing.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks! Two more proposals.... ;-)

Comment: Hmmm.  Still a problem with the first column.  The other two columns look good, both versions.

Comment: Yay!  *Much* better!

Comment: Awesome, thank you! The only follow-up question I have is whether you can think of a way to help Overleaf not mark this as an error in the editor `unclosed open group { found at $, unexpected $ after \begin{alignedat}` (https://i.imgur.com/dwGRCwD.png).

Comment: @danijar I am sorry, I do not use `overleaf`. All I can do is to make sure that the code runs on an updated TeXLive installation. `overleaf` unfortunately used an outdated installation, and I cannot use it (or more precisely I do not want to).

Comment: Okay, I understand the reasons for not using Overleaf :) For others, I've found that you can disable the editor checks with `%%begin novalidate` before and `%%end novalidate` after the block of LaTeX source.

Comment: Do you know how to move the spacing details above above into a macro? Maybe it would be possible to have an environment as replacement for `alignedat` that inserts `eqmakebox` automatically together with a replacement for `underbrace`? I don't know how to do the former --- the latter seems straightforward except for the `{}` that should be inlined to fix operator spacing.

Comment: @danijar You can always define a macro but the question is what the input and expected outputs are. What do you want to achieve, and with which input?

Comment: The goal is to have the second code example from my question produce the same output as your solution. Ideally, the only necessary changes would be to swap `alignedat` to `newalignedat` and `\underbrace` to `\newunderbrace`, in addition to the code that defines the `newalignedat` environment and the `\newunderbrace` macro.

Comment: @danijar One can do that, but it will require the macro to distinguish many cases (is there a plus or minus and so on), and whatever one achieves this way will be fragile in the sense that if you do not precisely follow the syntax, there will be errors. If you ask a question on this you will most likely get some answers but I would like to warn you that (according to my experience) these will be fragile (not work on the arXiv and/or require lualatex and/or not work any longer in a few years because once again some conventions have changed. Personally I recommend not going that path.

Comment: Okay, I see. Thanks for the recommendation. It just seems to me that moving this logic into a macro would make it easier to fix my document with many of these equation blocks, e.g. when switching to different LaTeX distributions.